# Register comdlg32.dll gets Regsvr32: DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Tags: windows, dll, regsvr32, common-dialog, comdlg32

I have Windows 7, 64-bit.

I'm trying to register a .dll (comdlg32.dll) using regsvr32. But I get an error that says the dll is read but the DLLRegistryServer entry point is not found.

I have run the command under both System32 and SysWOW64 and I have run my commands with "Run As Administrator".

My old MSComDlg.CommonDialog component is no longer working with 64-bit.

Comment: Use "depends.exe" tool to verify that the entry point is correctly exported

Comment: @patriiice how should i use it?

Comment: Just do File/Open on your dll and search in the export list to find the exact name "DllRegisterServer". If it's missing then you will have to find why...

Comment: @patriiice ok i found the dllregisterserver on the right panel. now what should i do?

Answer (score 15):

comdlg32.dll is not a COM DLL and cannot be registered.

One way to confirm this for yourself is to run this command:

```
dumpbin /exports comdlg32.dll
```

You'll see that comdlg32.dll doesn't contain a `DllRegisterServer` method. Hence RegSvr32.exe won't work.

That's your answer.

---

ComDlg32.dll is a a system component. (exists in both c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64)  Trying to replace it or override any registration with an older version could corrupt the rest of Windows.

---

I can help more, but I need to know what MSComDlg.CommonDialog is. What does it do and how is it supposed to work? And what version of ComDlg32.dll are you trying to register (and where did you get it)?

Comment: I'm running a VBScript macro on a software called QlikView for data analysis. On all the old machines including the ones with Win7 32-bit, this MSComDlg.CommonDialog used to open a file dialog but it does not work in win7 64-bit. i think i have replaced the file once. still haven't faced any corruptions. the file version of the comdlg32.dll i'm using is 6.1.7601.17514

Comment: I think Simon's answer about comctl32.ocx is what you want.

Comment: I registered the ocx file successfully. Now I'm trying to run this test: SET objComDlg32 = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog") where i get an error that says this ActiveX component cannot be created. Any idea?

Comment: `dumpbin is not recognized as an internal or external command.` :(

Comment: @DiAlex - it comes with Visual Studio and Visual C++.  Look in your VC\bin directory.

Comment: @dialex You can also use `dumpbin` from [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 12):

comdlg32.dll is not really a COM dll (you can't register it).

What you need is **comdlg32.ocx** which contains the MSComDlg.CommonDialog COM class (and indeed relies on comdlg32.dll to work). Once you get ahold on a comdlg32.ocx, then you will be able to do `regsvr32 comdlg32.ocx`.

Comment: that will help. Thanks! I'll try to try with the ocx file. Sorry I'm not really good at this stuff. All I want is to run a simple file dialog on a software that supports VBScript macros. It worked on all previous versions on windows but it's not working on Win7 64-bit.

Comment: Ok @Simon Mourier I registered the ocx file successfully. Now I'm trying to run this test: 
 SET objComDlg32 = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog") where i get an error that says this ActiveX component cannot be created

Comment: Now, that maybe a 64/32 bit issue. You can't use Common Control OCX with a 64 bit program at all. Also make sure comdlg32.dll exist in Windows\system32 directory or aside the OCX.

Comment: Yes I checked that. comdlg32.dll exists in the folder and also ocx. Is there a replacement that does the same thing?

Comment: What happens when you have registered an .ocx and works fine when your project is set for x86 CPU, but tells you that the class is not registered when you set x64 CPU? Do you happen to know any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 5):

Registering DLL for Fundsite

Outdated or missing comdlg32.ocx runtime library can be the problem of causing this error.
Make sure comdlg32.ocx file is not corrupted otherwise Download the File comdlg32.ocx (~60 Kb Zip).

Download the file and extract the comdlg32.ocx to your the Windows\System32 folder or Windows\SysWOW64. In my case i started with Windows\System32 but it didn’t work at my end, so I again saved in Windows\SysWOW64.

Type following command from Start, Run dialog:“c:\windows>System32\regsvr32 Comdlg32.ocx “ or “c:\windows>SysWOW64\regsvr32 Comdlg32.ocx ”

Now Comdlg.ocx File is register and next step is to register the DLL

1. Copy the Fundsite.Text.Encoding. dll into .Net Framework folder for 64bit on below path
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
2. Then on command prompt and go to directory C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 and then run the following command as shown below.

This will register the dll successfully.

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727>regasm "Dll Name".dll**

Comment: REGASM reference is the solution for generic "DLLRegistryServer entry point is not found" error message issue

Comment: Download the file from where?

Answer (score 1):

Have you unistalled your Internet Explorer?
I did, and I had the same issues, if so, you have to:

1. Reactivate IE (Control Panel -- Programs and Features -- Turn Windows features on or off).
2. restarting the computer
3. (important!) running Windows Update to get all available updates for Microsoft Explorer
4. restarting the computer (again)

Finally it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with COMDLG32.OCX and MSFLXGRD.OCX in Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2010. It's an MFC application.

Then I downloaded its zip file from the google after extracting copy them at following paths:

```
C:\Windows\System32 (*For 32-bit machine*)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (*For 64-bit machine*)
```

Then run Command Prompt as an ***Administrator*** then run the following commands:

```
For Windows 64-bit systems c:\windows\SysWOW64\ regsvr32 comdlg32.ocx
c:\windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 msflxgrd.ocx (My machine is 64-bit configuration)
```

For Windows 32-bit systems c:\windows\System32\ regsvr32 comdlg32.ocx

c:\windows\System32\regsvr32 msflxgrd.ocx

On successfully updation of the above cmds it shows succeed message.

Answer (score 0):

Information about missing entry point error installing legacy VB6 compiled applications on Windows 10 which I hope could be useful to someone.

Missing OCX files can be found in the "OS\System folder" of the Visual Basic 6.0 installer package. 
Today I copied the relevant OCX file (from our network) to the local computer

And then I typed the commands below, as administrator, which normally work to register it.

```
cd \windows\syswow64
regsvr32.exe /u mscomctl.ocx
regsvr32.exe /i mscomctl.ocx
```

(add the path to the locally copied file for the /i command)

However today I got errors from both these regsvr32.exe commands.

The second error was giving the DllImport missing entry point error which is similar to the error mentioned by the original poster.

To resolve, one of the things I tried was leaving out the switch -

```
regsvr32.exe mscomctl.ocx
```

To my surprise it then said it was successful. 
To confirm, the application started up properly afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

SOLUTION OF Regsvr32: DllRegisterServer entry point was not found,

1. Go to systemdrive(generally c:)\system32 and search file "Regsvr32.exe"
2. Right click and click in properties and go to security tab and click in advanced button.
3. Click in owner tab and click edit and select administrators and click ok.
4. Click in permissions
5. Click in change permissions.
6. Choose administrators and click edit and put tick on full control and click ok.
7. Similarly, choose SYSTEM and edit and put tick on full control and click ok and click in other dialog box which are opened.
8. Now .dll files can be registered and error don't come, you should re-install any software whose dll files was not registered during installation.

Answer (score -4):

I also had the similar problem while registering myinfo.dll file in windows 7. Following work for me:
Create a short cut on your desktop
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\myinfo.dll
right click on the short cut just created and select as Run as administrator.

Comment: Isn't that just the same as running cmd as administrator?